# AngularJS/Ionic – Can't add identical data to an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm having a weird issue (I'm very new to angular and even JS, however I believe this should work as I tested it using node in my terminal and it was fine). I've created a button that basically should add "hi" as an entry to an array. However, it only adds it once, and then stop working. I expected it to just continue to add "hi", "hi"...etc. – I should mention this was using "push".

So I've tried the following, getting the index of the last entry, and then adding "hi" as the new entry as seen below:

```js
$scope.attend2 = function() {
         arrayLength = $scope.eventAttending.length;
         $scope.eventAttending[arrayLength] = "Hi";
        };
```

I'm still having the same issue. I first fed in the index of the last array entry as the data, and this would work fine because the data being added was different each time (e.g. eventAttending[1] = 1 then eventAttending[2] = 2), However it seems to not work when it's the same data;e.g. eventAttending[1] = "hi" then eventAttending[2] = "hi" – in this case I get "hi" in array index 1, but it stops there.

Thanks for any help,

Chris

Comment: **Maybe the problem** is not related with how you are adding that data to the array, but with **how are you using that data**.

Is it possible that you are displaying that array using a **ng-repeat directive**?

Comment: Yes that's correct, I'm using ng-repeat. Is that what's causing it! it doesn't print multiple identical entries? Is there a way around this?

Comment: Yes, you can use track by. I added an example in my response

Comment: Did it helped you? If so, can you accept my answer so anyone with same issue can find it?

Answer (score 1):

Try pushing the value in the array:

```
$scope.eventAttending.push("Hi");
```

Comment: Hi Oscar, thank you for your reply. I tried push but to no avail, the same thing happens...very odd.

Answer (score 1):

Just define an empty array in the controller and push the string message on click event of button

**Example**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.hiArray = [];
  $scope.onClick=function(){
    $scope.hiArray.push('Hi');
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.10" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="onClick()" >Add Hi</button> <br>
    {{hiArray}}
  </body>

</html>
```

**[See Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bq45ovcfUmovuznCZp2E?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion – I've tried this, having an empty array then using push to add "hi" and I'm still only able to add it once, then it ceases to add. Really odd...

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try to make the array multi dimensional:

```
$scope.eventAttending=[];
$scope.attend2 = function() {
         var arrayLength = $scope.eventAttending.length;
         $scope.eventAttending.push({arrayLength:"Hi"});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using that array inside an ng-repeat, and by default, that directive uses content to differentiate items.

You can solve it using 'track by' to change the variable it uses to track elements:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">{{item}}</div>
```